# How can I force an exception to be thrown when deserializing a dictionary with duplicated keys from JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a data model with a `Dictionary<string, string>` of attributes as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Under certain rare circumstances, I am receiving JSON with duplicated property names for `Attributes`, e.g.:

```
{
   "name":"Object Name",
   "attributes":{
      "key1":"adfadfd",
      "key1":"adfadfadf"
   }
}
```

I would like for an exception to be thrown in such a situation, however when I deserialize with Json.NET there is no error and the dictionary instead contains the last value encountered.  How can I force an error in such a situation?

---

As a workaround, I am currently declaring attributes as a list of key/value pairs:

```
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Attributes { get; set;
```

This requires me to serialize the attributes in the following format:

```
"attributes": [
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "value": "adfadfd"
    },
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "value": "adfadfadf"
    }
]
```

Then later I can detect the duplicate.  However, I would prefer to use the more compact JSON object syntax rather than the JSON array syntax, and declare Attributes as a dictionary.

Comment: "I can accept dictionary but know when it was malformed " what do you mean? what is the problem. Can you post what you have and what you want if you have the same key and different values for example as it is in your post?

Comment: The problem is that if the json dictionary is malformed with having repeated keys then the dictionary that I receive is a valid 1 item dictionary. I would not want it to successfully model bind in that situation.

Comment: Creating my dictionary from the List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> works fine and is not the issue.  My question is around  ideally accepting a json dictionary and being able to know when it was malformed vs it having repeated items removed before I can validate it.

Comment: I apologize if unclear but I thought I explained in the question. The first is a working approach. The second represents a valid version  of  what I would Ideally want to use and the third a malformed dictionary  that leads to the problem. When I do this I am unable or don't know how to know wen it was malformed as it arrives with duplicate keys already removed. Id like to be able to not proceed if the format is not correct verses it have been scrubbed. I am trying to figure out how to better represent my question with code.

Comment: Seems both System.Text.Json and Json.NET set rather than add dictionary entries, which prevents duplicate key exceptions from being thrown, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/MDjS0N.  JSON objects with duplicated property names aren't actually malformed by the way.  They standard allows them but recommends against them.  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-4: *When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair only...*

Comment: Thanks. If so I suppose I need  to stick with my original approach.

Comment: Or you could write a custom converter.  Do you know the serializer you are using?

Comment: NewtonSoft 3.1.7

Comment: This was based on following a tutorial  on Pluralsight a few years ago. Most of my concern goes in to business logic so  I'm not well versed in this aspect (or not versed at all). I am not committed to this serializer.

Comment: It's pulled in via Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 3.1.7. My mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that, when deserializing a dictionary from a JSON object with duplicated property names, Json.NET (and also System.Text.Json) silently populate the dictionary with the value from the last duplicated key.  (Demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MDjS0N).) This is not entirely surprising, as JSON RFC 8259 [states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-4):

> When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable. Many implementations report the last name/value pair only...

Since you don't want that, you can create a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) that throws an error in the event of duplicated property names:

```
public class NoDuplicateKeysDictionaryConverter<TValue> : NoDuplicateKeysDictionaryConverter<Dictionary<string, TValue>, TValue> 
{
}

public class NoDuplicateKeysDictionaryConverter<TDictionary, TValue> : JsonConverter<TDictionary> where TDictionary : IDictionary<string, TValue>
{
    public override TDictionary ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TDictionary existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return typeof(TDictionary).IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TDictionary)) == null ? throw new JsonSerializationException("null value") : default;
        reader.AssertTokenType(JsonToken.StartObject);
        var dictionary = existingValue ?? (TDictionary)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(TDictionary)).DefaultCreator();
        // Todo: decide whether you want to clear the incoming dictionary.
        while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            var key = (string)reader.AssertTokenType(JsonToken.PropertyName).Value;
            var value = serializer.Deserialize<TValue>(reader.ReadToContentAndAssert());
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.add#exceptions
            // Add() will throw an ArgumentException when an element with the same key already exists in the IDictionary<TKey,TValue>.
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, TDictionary value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader AssertTokenType(this JsonReader reader, JsonToken tokenType) => 
        reader.TokenType == tokenType ? reader : throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}, expected {1}", reader.TokenType, tokenType));
    
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Then add it to your model as follows:

```
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(NoDuplicateKeysDictionaryConverter<string>))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
```

And an `ArgumentException` will be thrown whenever an attempt is made to add duplicated keys to the dictionary.

Demo fidde [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dkmfco).

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I will dig in to it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/2b0f7a2492bbedbf5e381d0468f503a99e834dbc/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L1444) for Json.NET, the code just does this:

```cs
dictionary[keyValue] = itemValue;
```

So one option is to write a wrapper for `Dictionary` that provides the functionality you want. We can pass through all calls, except for the indexer, which passes through to `Add` instead which will cause an exception.

> Techinically speaking, the Json.NET code only asks for an `IDictionary`, not an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` but then you wouldn't be able to read from it without casting and/or unboxing.

```cs
     const string json =@"
     {
        ""name"":""Object Name"",
        ""attributes"":{
           ""key1"":""adfadfd"",
           ""key1"":""adfadfadf""
        }
     }
     ";
     Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json));
```

```cs
 public class Model
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public StrictDictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
 }
 
 public class StrictDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
 {
     public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> InnerDictionary {get; set; } = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
     
     public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => InnerDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
     public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) => InnerDictionary.Add(key, value);
     void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp) => ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>) InnerDictionary).Add(kvp);
     bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp) => ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>) InnerDictionary).Contains(kvp);
     void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int i) => ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>) InnerDictionary).CopyTo(array, i);
     public void Clear() => InnerDictionary.Clear();
     public bool Remove(TKey key) => InnerDictionary.Remove(key);
     bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp) => ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>) InnerDictionary).Remove(kvp);
     public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) => InnerDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
     public ICollection<TKey> Keys => InnerDictionary.Keys;
     public ICollection<TValue> Values => InnerDictionary.Values;
     public int Count => InnerDictionary.Count;
     public bool IsReadOnly => ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>) InnerDictionary).IsReadOnly;
     public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() => InnerDictionary.GetEnumerator();
     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => InnerDictionary.GetEnumerator();

     public TValue this[TKey key]
     {
         get => InnerDictionary[key];
         set => InnerDictionary.Add(key, value);
     }
 }
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iBz6eR)